# Excel Macro - How to show date value as dates in datavalue of a pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

My code uses `AddDataField` as below

`PivotTables("pvt1").AddDataField PivotTables("pvt1").PivotFields("Interview_dt"),"intdt"`

If I do not give function option, the default is `xlCount` and showing it as count of dates instead I want date to be shown as date without any aggregate function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You more probably want to use `AddFields`:

```
PivotTables("pvt1").AddFields Array("Interview_dt")
```